# Getting the first element of Set in JSP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, el

I have this in my entity

```
public class Contact implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Set<Abonnement> abonnements = new HashSet<Abonnement>(0);
    // ..
```

in my jsp I need just the **first** element, I don't want to iterate over the whole `HashSet` so I try this

```
${contact.abonnements[0]}
```

but I get this error :

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property '0' not found on type org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet
```

Comment: A `Set` is not ordered so there's no such thing as "first element". You should use a different data structure that keeps order of elements in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that `Set` are not ordered but i'm sure i will have just one element in my Set the order is not important So I can access to the first element like this :

```
<c:if test="${contact.abonnements.size() == 1 }">
        ${contact.abonnements.iterator().next()} 
</c:if>
```

Comment: As [explained in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator()), iterator's elements are *"returned in no particular order"* so you could end up seeing a different item during each execution.

Comment: thanks man for your explanation i didn't know that i could end up seeing a different item during each execution but in my case my Set contain just one element that's why i want just the first element ;)

Comment: If you *know* there will ever be just one element then arguably using a collection is superfluous. This answer is not going to help anyone who *really* needs to use a `Set`.